# Fire AJAX twice from same component (simultaneously)

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Well, I want to fire AJAX from one component but for two destinations, let some code clear out what I mean with that :

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

        <p:inputText value="#{someBean.someProperty}" >
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="growl" listener="#{someBean.someListenerMethod}"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="updatable" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="#{someBean.someProperty}" id="updatable" />
```

So once the blur event occures, the `<h:outputText>` and the `<p:growl>` will be "AJAXed" (in primefaces tongue : updated). I had this example in mind and anther one that replaces the second `<f:ajax>` with an update attribute in `<p:inputText>`, but neither done me good.

Hopefully, you're going to know better and aid me solving this out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more than one item inside the `render` attribute :

```
<f:ajax event="blur" render="growl updatable" listener="#{someBean.someListenerMethod}"/>
```

Comment: tried that one out but used a comma to separate growl and updatable, I feel stupid. En tout cas : merci !

Comment: I feel sometimes too, keep in mind you don't need comma separator for `styleClass` too if you use if somewhere else!

Comment: Comma as client ID separator works in PrimeFaces ajax components (`<p:ajax>`, `<p:commandXxx>`, etc), but indeed not in `<f:ajax>`. That's probably where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: @BalusC : good to know my confusion is based on a fact, now I can avoid it next time, thanks for your remark.